# x86 NASM Indirect Far Jump In Real Mode

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I have been messing around with a multi-stage bootloader and I have got all of my code to work, except for the last part: *The Jump*. I have gotten this code to work out before now but I wanted to make it more modular by replacing this line:

```
jmp 0x7E0:0
```

With this one:

```
jmp far [Stage2Read + SectorReadParam.bufoff]
```

Instead of hard coding where the code will load in, I wanted to do an indirect jump to it. Here's the rest of my code:

```
; This is stage 1 of a multi-stage bootloader

bits 16                      
org 0x7C00            

jmp 0:boot_main   

%include "io16.inc"

boot_main:
    ; setup the new stack
    cli               
    mov ax, 0x100       
    mov ss, ax          
    mov bp, 0x4000       
    mov sp, bp          
    sti 

    ; Setup data segment
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax

    ; Save which drive we booted from
    mov [Stage2Read + SectorReadParam.drive], dl    

    ; Home-made BIOS wrapper to read sectors into memory
    mov si, Stage2Read
    call ReadSectors                               

    ; Change to new data segment
    mov ax, [Stage2Read + SectorReadParam.bufseg]
    mov ds, ax             

    ;jmp 0x7E0:0                                    ; THIS WORKS
    jmp far [Stage2Read + SectorReadParam.bufoff]   ; BUT THIS DOES NOT

; Used as the parameters for ReadSectors
Stage2Read: ISTRUC SectorReadParam     
    AT SectorReadParam.bufoff,  dd 0
    AT SectorReadParam.bufseg,  dw 0x07E0
    AT SectorReadParam.numsecs, db 1
    AT SectorReadParam.track,   db 0
    AT SectorReadParam.sector,  db 2
    AT SectorReadParam.head,    db 0
    AT SectorReadParam.drive,   db 0        ; needs to be initialized!
IEND

; Ending
times 510-($-$$) db 0    
dw 0xAA55
```

Remember all this code has been tested and works except for the **indirect far jump** to work. That's all I need to get this to work. I was wondering if maybe the indirect far jump implicitly is using for example `ds` so that the address `Stage2Read + SectorReadParam.bufoff` would be incorrect. This is really bugging me because it is so seemingly simple. I would like help!

Comment: Maybe I am misreading this but you have `AT SectorReadParam.bufoff,  dd 0` . That is **DD** (32-bit value) set to zero. Seems to me that `jmp far dword [Stage2Read + SectorReadParam.bufoff]` would be jumping to 0x0000:0x0000?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Oops yeah that was a bug, but still, it doesn't work...

Comment: I've placed the *DD* / *DW* bug back into your question to keep the original comments I wrote above relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a couple of bugs in your original code. The first was the fact that you had the offset using a *DD* (32-bit *DWORD*) instead of a 16-bit *WORD*. This line:

```
AT SectorReadParam.bufoff, dd 0
```

Should have been:

```
AT SectorReadParam.bufoff, dw 0
```

When you specify the memory operand for the *FAR JMP* by default (in your case) it is relative to the *DS* (data segment). Before the *FAR JMP* you set *DS* to a new value, so the *JMP* memory operand will read the memory address from the wrong segment (0x07e0 instead of 0x0000).

You can either set *DS* after you *JMP* or you can change the memory operand to be relative to *CS* (which is still the segment with the data) using an override. It could look like this:

```
jmp far [CS:Stage2Read + SectorReadParam.bufoff]
```

Comment: So it DID use an implicit register... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're expecting `jmp far` to read its destination address from `Stage2Read + SectorReadParam.bufoff`, which is essentially `0x0000:Stage2Read + SectorReadParam.bufoff` (`ds` = 0x0000).

However, just before the jump, `ds` is set to 0x07e0, so it seems to me that your code is reading its destination address from `0x07e0:Stage2Read + SectorReadParam.bufoff`.